# Adapt data to ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

In one of my activity I have `EditText`, Submit `Button` and a `ListView`. The data of `ListView` are retrived from database. To retrive data from database and adapt to `ListView` I used the following code.

```
private void loadList() {
    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    mylist.clear();
    List<Data> catDesc = dbhelper.getCatMasterDesc(id);
    ArrayAdapter<Data> adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list, catDesc);
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.masListView1);
    lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And i call this method every time whenever I update the database to show updated listview.

```
String str = category.getText().toString();
yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    dbhelper.UpdateMasterDesc(str);
    loadList(); // see here.
}
});
```

This is the way I am updating my `ListView`. I think this is not a good way. If yes means please suggest me how can I update my `ListView` Whenever I update the database.

Thank You.

Comment: call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter when you update to refresh listview

Comment: @Raghunandan It is not working friend

Comment: call this adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after update. this will refresh your listview http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @Gunaseelan That is the wrong way to do..Because you are creating new adapter everytime, so `notifyDataSetChanged()` won't work

Comment: @Pragnani So what you are telling is my way is correct. Is it right friend.

Comment: @Gunaseelan a suggestion use a activity context in place of getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

notifyDataSetchanged() is the answer as proposed by Raghunandan.

But before calling it, you need to update your object data which has been included in your list of catDesc.

Judging from your code I believe what

```
dbhelper.UpdateMasterDesc(str);
```

does is adding a new category? If yes, do a

```
catDesc.add(new Data(whatever you need to declare it with str))
```

before calling notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: My Data class didn't have user defined constructor.

Comment: In that case may I ask how do you return a list of data in `dbhelper.getCatMasterDesc(id);`?